# Hibernate Multiple @OneToOne all with the same id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have three classes

> 1- Narrative
>
> 2- NarrativeData
>
> 3- NarrativeSponsershipe

The `Narrative` class has `oneToOne` relation with both `NarrativeData` and `narrativeSponership`.

I need the three classes to have the same id. In other words, I need the three classes to be mapped using the id.

The id of the `Narrative` class is annotated using `GenericGenerator` and the property parameter's value is set to the associated `NarrativeData` field. This way the `Narrative` and `NarrativeData` will has the same id but the `NarrativeSponsership` will take another id.

How can I achieve the three classes having the same id?

Comment: For the id of Narrative, use @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO), then persist and get the generated Id from Narrative, and put it for NarrativeData and NarrativeSponsership..

Comment: Why is it so important that they have the same ID?

Comment: @AlanHay is not important. You are right maybe this is the solution. But for the sake of knowledge, is this possible?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6839336/1356423