# Hibernate Primary Foreign Key field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 2 simple tables in database. They look like:

```
T1                                      T2
ID    NUMBER     Primary key            ID    NUMBER    Primary key & Foreign key from T1
Value VARCHAR                           Value VARCHAR
```

How does hibernate entity for T2 look like?
I tried to do it with @Embeddable class containing T1 mapped-class object but this doesn't work.
Thanks.

UPD: the full use case when I need such a structure is below:
I have business entities tables, containing some data for specific business users, and Company table with Id and value fields too, and I want to create CompanyToBEntity table, containing data about what company can access what object.(objects are any row of bus.entities).

So I think this structure fits this case.

pic describing it better:

[image]

Comment: if ID in T2 is primary and foreign key; then why do you require T2 at all?

Comment: added my use case, will try to add link to picture, to describe the case better

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833370/jpa-onetoone-with-shared-id-can-i-do-this-better you have to use OneToOne & MapsId

Comment: Another option is to Map one Entity to the two tables using the @SecondaryTable annotation. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Unidirectional one-to-one association vi primary key association` 
something like -

**T1 Mapping**

```
@Id  
@Column(name="ID")  
private Integer ID;
```

**T2 Mapping**

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
private T1 t1;
```

For more reference you visit [here](http://www.javamakeuse.com/2014/10/hibernate-4-one-to-one-mapping-example_31.html), the example is based on hbm.xml

Comment: with this i get "No identifier specified for entity" for which hibenrate version is it?

Comment: @wutzebaer, It's Hibernate 4