# Mapping an @Embeddable in a separate table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Two tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  x TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
  foo_id INT REFERENCES foo (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  y TEXT,
  z TEXT
);
```

...can be mapped like so:

```
@Table(name = "foo")
@SecondaryTable(name = "bar", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
class Foo {

  @Id
  int id;

  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "y", column = @Column(table = "bar")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "z", column = @Column(table = "bar"))
  })
  Bar bar;
}

@Embeddable
class Bar {
  String y;
  String z;
}
```

Is there a less awkward way to do this mapping, using either just standard JPA annotations, or else Hibernate-specific annotations (and without introducing a parent reference in the embeddable object)?

Compare this to how easily a collection of `@Embeddable` objects can be referenced using an `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable`.

Comment: Can't you simply map it using @ElementCollection but hide that implementation detail i.e. don;t expose the collection but provide set/getBar methods that manipulate the collection?

Comment: That would work, too, but would be even uglier than the verbose annotations above :-)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the late answer, but the question interested me so I figured I'd take a crack at it.

A more elegant solution is to make the contents of `bar` an Entity instead of an Embeddable, and to use a OneToOne relationship instead of an Embedded. You also need to remember to use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` instead of `@JoinColumn`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
class Bar {
  @Id
  int fooId;

  String y;
  String z;
}

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo {
  @Id
  int id;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  Bar bar;
}
```

The biggest advantage is that `Foo` no longer needs to know about the contents of `Bar`. Depending on your DB's naming strategy, you may also need to specify the column name of `fooId` in `Bar` with something like `@Column(name = "foo_id")`.

Comment: Should have been more clear that the database schema is fixed (no unique identifiers for bar), so this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: @ejain in your DDL for Bar you have this: `foo_id INT REFERENCES foo (id) ON DELETE CASCADE`. That's all the unique identifier you need. If you're saying that there can be multiple rows in that table (bar) that refer to the same Foo entity, then even your original SecondaryTable solution wouldn't work. If the SecondaryTable solution works, so will this one.

Comment: Good point, but looks `fooId` would have to be set explicitly? Might be able to use `@MapsId` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528193/1144085), but that approach also has some drawbacks compared to using an `@Embeddable`.

Comment: @ejain I’ve tested this answer and it works perfectly for what you asked. It’s also exactly how what you asked is supposed to be done. The link you mentioned in your comment is not even the same issue.

Comment: If you don’t want to mark this answer as correct for whatever reason, no one is forcing you. But my answer is exactly what you asked for. If you have a different problem now, you should post a new question, or at least modify this one.

Comment: Your current solution loses the foreign key relationship, and only works as long as you manually set both primary keys to identical values... Just replace `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` with `@MapsId @JoinColumn(name = "id")`, and I'll accept your solution!

Comment: If you're talking about a foreign-key relationship in Bar linking to Foo, you never had this in your original problem or solution.

Comment: If you now want one, you don't want to use `@MapsId` which is really only useful for embedded objects. Instead, you want to use the standard solution for when your primary key is also a foreign key.

Comment: Simply also add `@Id` to the relationship. So instead of adding `@Id int fooId;`, you would add `@Id @OneToOne Foo foo;`.

Comment: The original `@Embedded` solution creates a foreign key that matches the DDL also posted above; looks like using `@MapsId` allows us to have a foreign key without having to make the relationship bidirectional.

Comment: Your original embedded solution does *not* create a foreign key, and that's not what `@MapsId` does. No part of your previous statement is correct.

Comment: What JPA implementation did you test this with? Hibernate (5.2.17) appears to create a foreign key constraint for both the `@Embedded` and the `@MapsId` solution: 
```Hibernate: drop table bar if exists
Hibernate: drop table foo if exists
Hibernate: create table bar (value varchar(255), foo_id binary not null, primary key (foo_id))
Hibernate: create table foo (id binary not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table bar add constraint FKdvoqij212wwl2bf14kwo55h55 foreign key (foo_id) references foo```

Comment: That’s the `@SecondaryTable` annotation that’s creating all of that. It has nothing to do with MapsId nor Embedded. Trust me, if you do as I say the Entity and Table annotations on Bar will create the Bar table, and the OneToOne will create the foreign key. Why don’t you actually try it and see if it works? Hint: it does.

Comment: The `@MapsId` solution is based on your solution, and doesn't use `@Embedded` or `@SecondaryTable`. It's possible that this is a blatant misuse of this annotation, but it appears to work, and doesn't require changing the Bar domain object to have a reference back to a Foo object.

Comment: I was hoping that my original assessment was wrong, but it’s clear that I was spot on. I, like most people here, use SO to exchange ideas and try to help people in good faith. If you don’t want to accept my help, the only people you’re hurting are those who are searching for an answer to this question in the future. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Here's an upvote for your troubles :-) Leaving the question open in case someone has a better solution that doesn't require changing the domain model or schema...