# Hibernate complains for null @Id in @OneToOne even if it is not null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I am trying to achieve `@OneToOne` association, using the same `@Id` between a `Car` and a `Person`. A `Person` is has an optional `Car`, but a `Car` has a required `Person` (hence I need a foreign key inside "cars" table pointing an existing `Person`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person")
    private Car car;

    /**
     * For hibernate
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "name")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Person person;

    public Car() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

}
```

My test case:

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@Test
public void test() {
    Person mike = new Person("Mike");
    personRepository.save(mike); //Saved sucessfully

    Person alice = new Person("Alice");
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setPerson(alice);
    car.setName(alice.getName());
    alice.setCar(car);
    personRepository.save(alice); //error
}
```

Stacktrace:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id
>   from null one-to-one property [com.project.entity.Car.person];
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException:
>   attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property
>   [com.project.entity.Car.person]

I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528193/6579265) on how to have a shared Id. The schema in database looks to be fine, and works exactly as I want. If i delete a Car, nothing happens. If I delete a person who owns a `Car`, his `Car` will be deleted from database as well.

The question is simple. **What do I do wrong?**

In case it plays any role (I doubt it), this is my datasource properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto = create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Disclaimer: It was not meant to be a Q&A)

The problem is in `@MapsId` annotation. Changing it to:

```
@MapsId("name") //Here
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "name")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Person person;
```

seems to fix the problem.

Comment: this takes my 1.5 days :/