# Hibernate: Join table on a.fk_id = b.id

Tags: hibernate

I'm working on a small project involving the game Re-Volt (1999), I'm trying to make a web page where you can see all the cars with their details (image, engine type, rating, speed etc.). I have a table `cars` where I the previous mentioned information and it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cars (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(25),
    thumbnail_id integer,
    engine_id integer,
    rating_id integer,
    speed integer,
    acc numeric,
    mass numeric
);
```

I am using Hibernate with Spring Boot, PostgreSQL for the database and Thymeleaf to display the data in a web page. I managed to use Hibernate to pull the data from `cars` and display it, all good, but now I want to join `cars` with table `thumbnails` on `cars.thumbnail_id = thumbnails.id` and display the column `image` from table `thumbnails` instead of `thumbnails_id`. This is what my `thumbnails` table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.thumbnails (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    image character varying(50)
);
```

And these are my entities:

```
// Car.java
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;

    @Column(name = "engine_id")
    private Integer engine_id;

    @Column(name = "rating_id")
    private Integer rating_id;

    @Column(name = "speed")
    private Integer speed;
    @Column(name = "acc")
    private Double acc;
    @Column(name = "mass")
    private Double mass;
}
```

```
// Thumbnail.java
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "thumbnails")
public class Thumbnail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
}
```

What I don't know how to do is properly code that `join` in. With my current code Hibernate matches the rows without considering the value of `thumbnail_id`, it simply does "car_1 = thumbnail_1" even if "car_1" has "thumbnail_id" equal to 12, it still matches it to the first thumbnail and not to the 12th. Can anyone help me out?

Edit: Basically, what I'm trying to achieve through Hibernate is the following SQL query:

```
SELECT c.name, t.image, c.engine_id, c.rating_id, c.speed, c.acc, c.mass
FROM cars c
JOIN thumbnails t
ON c.thumbnails_id = t.id;
```

Comment: Can you please try with @MapsId- Take a loot at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508864/hibernate-complains-for-null-id-in-onetoone-even-if-it-is-not-null

Comment: I added `@MapsId("id")` to the `thumbnail` field but it doesn't change anything, the join still doesn't consider `ON cars.thumbnail_id = thumbnails.id`.

Comment: did you also add reference of Car in Thumbnail and use mappedBy in car like mentioned in the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508864/hibernate-complains-for-null-id-in-onetoone-even-if-it-is-not-null

Comment: I didn't, because then where would my `image` column go?

Comment: There is no thumbnails_id in your cars table. You'd have to do "JOIN thumbnails t ON c.thumbnail.id = t.id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cars Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "thumbnail_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;

    @Column(name = "engine_id")
    private Integer engine_id;

    @Column(name = "rating_id")
    private Integer rating_id;

    @Column(name = "speed")
    private Integer speed;
    @Column(name = "acc")
    private Double acc;
    @Column(name = "mass")
    private Double mass;
```

Thumbnail Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thumbnails")
public class Thumbnail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
```

Since you want to achieve the **select with join** and in case of one to one association **N+1 problem would not allow** you to do so, you need to modify your repository as below to **add EntityGraph**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.mahesh.tt.model.Car;

public interface TutorialRepository2 extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
    
     @Override
        @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"thumbnail"})
        List<Car> findAll();
}
```

This will make sure that your thumbnail data is fetched with join and not with multiple select statements.

1. You can see the query generated in the console

Hibernate:

```
 select
            car0_.id as id1_0_0_,
            thumbnail1_.id as id1_1_1_,
            car0_.acc as acc2_0_0_,
            car0_.engine_id as engine_i3_0_0_,
            car0_.mass as mass4_0_0_,
            car0_.name as name5_0_0_,
            car0_.rating_id as rating_i6_0_0_,
            car0_.speed as speed7_0_0_,
            car0_.thumbnail_id as thumbnai8_0_0_,
            thumbnail1_.image as image2_1_1_ 
        from
            cars car0_ 
        left outer join
            thumbnails thumbnail1_ 
                on car0_.thumbnail_id=thumbnail1_.id
```

2. You can see the result in API response.

[image]

3. You can see the sample data in the database

Cars -

[image]

Thumbnail -

[image]

Comment: I found a solution thanks to your previous comments and help from another user. I also tried with the code you wrote  (without the `@EntityGraph ...`) and it does the job, I'll mark your comment as the correct answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work thanks to your comments. What I did was mention `thumbnail_id` in the `@JoinColumn` annotation (thanks to @blau comment) and add `@MapsId("id")` (thanks to @Mahesh comment). So this is what I have in my `Car.java` class:

```
// Car.java
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "thumbnail_id") // I changed this
    @MapsId("id") // and added this
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;

    @Column(name = "engine_id")
    private Integer engine;

    @Column(name = "rating_id")
    private Integer rating;

    @Column(name = "speed")
    private Integer speed;
    @Column(name = "acc")
    private Double acc;
    @Column(name = "mass")
    private Double mass;
}
```