# Map/Access entities with composite key

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In my application I have 3 core classes as described below.

```
public class Semana {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Integer series;

    private String observacao;

    private Integer ordenacao;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "semana")
    @JsonBackReference
    @OrderBy("ordenacao asc ")
    private List<TreinoOrdenado> treinoOrdenados;
 }
```

```
public class TreinoOrdenado {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_semana")
    private Semana semana;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_treino")
    private Treino treino; // can be repeated in the database but with different "ordenacao" 

    private Integer ordenacao;

}
```

```
@Table(name = "exercicio_ordenado")
public class ExercicioOrdenado {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_treino")
    @JsonBackReference
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Treino treino;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_exercicio")
    private Exercicio exercicio;

    private Integer ordenacao;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinTable(name = "parametro")
   private Parametro parametro;

}
```

And this **Parametro** class which is a relationship between those 3 classes.

```
public class Parametro {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ParametroId parametroId = new ParametroId();

    @MapsId("semana")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "semana_id")
    private Semana semana;

    @MapsId("treino")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "treino_id")
    private TreinoOrdenado treino;

    @MapsId("exercicio")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exercicio_id")
    private ExercicioOrdenado exercicio;

    private Integer series;

    private String repeticoes;

    private String observacao;

}
```

```
public class ParametroId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "semana_id")
    private Long semana;

    @Column(name = "treino_id")
    private Long treino;

    @Column(name = "exercicio_id")
    private Long exercicio;

}
```

So, here is my problem. I want to be able to access the **Parametro** from it's parent class **ExercicioOrdenado**, but in order to be distinguishable in the database the class Parametro needs the reference from the other two (Semana, TreinoOrdenado).

With my current mapping I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK73ewcy2r50kw71o4he51dkolv:parametro 
[parametro_exercicio_id,parametro_semana_id,parametro_treino_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (parametro [id])
```

I can persist paremetros in the database with:

```
   parametros.setSemana(semana);
   parametros.setExercicio(exercicioOrdenado);
   parametros.setTreino(treinoOrdenado);
   parametroRepository.save(parametros);
```

But I can't retrieve from ExercicioOrdenado with the mapping.

I don't know the right approach to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i now a way...

To do this we can use @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId annotation.
In this link have exemples.
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys

```
@Entity
public class Parametro {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ParametroId parametroId;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exercicio_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_exercicio_id")
    private ExercicioOrdenado exercicio;    

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "semana_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_semana_id")
    private Semana semana;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "treino_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_treino_id")
    private TreinoOrdenado treino;

    private Integer series;

    private String repeticoes;

    private String observacao;
}

@Embeddable
public class ParametroId {


    private log id;

    private log semana;


    private log treino;

    private log exercicio;

}
```

I believe that this is the way to create a personalized primary key using jpa. I have not tested the relationships of entities in the primary key. I know that there is more than one form to do that.

[JPA @OneToOne with Shared ID -- Can I do this Better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833370/jpa-onetoone-with-shared-id-can-i-do-this-better)

Comment: Hi, but even with this code I can't map and retrieve _Parametro_ on the _ExercicioOrdenado_ side. It still say I have the wrong number of foreign keys. `foreign key (FK73ewcy2r50kw71o4he51dkolv:parametro [parametro_exercicio_id,parametro_semana_id,parametro_treino_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (parametro [id])`.

Comment: Hey, in thik the problem are ParametroId  dont have the reference in class, just a id. I editing the answer. Try again :S. I change the anotations.

Comment: I read the documentation you posted and I think I found my way by following their example. In "Parametro" I changed the mapping to '@ManyToOne' and in "ExercicioOrdenado" I did the mapping with '@OneToMany' using only "exercicio_id" as '@JoinColumn', the application stopped giving an error and I managed to recover the data from the database like this. However, to update an entity, it ended up duplicating the data in the database instead of updating, I will investigate further, but I will give this question here as answered.