# how do i create entity class for a table having primary key as foreign key?

Tags: java, oop, spring-data-jpa, entity

how do i create entity for **area_item_table** which have foreign key as primary key

the Item entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Item.ITEM)
public class Item {

  @Id
  @Column(name = ITEM_ID)
  private long itemId;
 
  @OneToOne
  @JoinTable(name = "area_item_table",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = ITEM_ID, referencedColumnName = ITEM_ID)},
      inverseJoinColumns = {
          @JoinColumn(name = AREA_ID, referencedColumnName = ID)})
  private Area area;

[removed get set and unrelated fields from entity]
}
```

the Area entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Area.AREA)
public class Area {

  @Id
  @Column(name = ID, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

[removed get set and unrelated fields from entity]
```

the table **area_item_table** :

| item_id | area_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 |

is there a way to create an Entity for this table without creating new primary key field

Comment: If it is `@OneToOne`, then you don't need an intermediate join table.

Comment: hey XtremeBaumer, without @JoinTable how can specify the table name ? or referenced columns?

Comment: You drop the table altogether. The target table is defined by the type. Lets say your `Item` table has a `area_id` column. Then in `Item` you do `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "area_id") private Area area;`. If you want the bidirectional mapping, then in `Area` you have a field like `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "area") private Item item;`. Though looking at the entity names, it would rather be `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToOne`

Comment: yes, that works but I didn't want to make any changes to the Item table so I created one table solely for mapping Item to Area. And now I want to create an entity for that table (item_area_table)

Comment: Why would you need an extra entity for that table?

Comment: I want to implement spring JPA repository for the table, and for that I need the entity.

Comment: Then I don't really understand your issue. You can simply create an entity, map it to the intermediate table and annotate both columns with `@Id`. Then you just need to adjust fields of `Item` and `Area` to connect to the intermediate entity

Comment: cannot create an entity like this because @Id requires something 

```@Entity
@Table(name = "item_area_table")
public class ItemArea { 

@Id
@Column
private Item item;

@Column
private Area area;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason that wouldn't work

Comment: it expects @IdClass in Entity

Comment: [I doubt that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833370/jpa-onetoone-with-shared-id-can-i-do-this-better)

Comment: Yes, I also went through that but it didn't help me. but I figured that maybe my spring boot version 1.3.5 is the reason or that question and my problem are different.